# Laravel @json in blade is giving coded result, but dump is correct

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello and welcome my Dear friends, I am not posting very often but I am dying from the pain of current problem I have encountered.

I am attaching pictures, but in short array that is created for JSON output in my recruitment page is giving coded outcome which looks like '\u3010\u5510\u6d25\u99c5\u3011\u226a\u5b8c\u5168' in all JSON elements.

I have tried to make mb_encode_check and it returns UTF-8 everywhere. In database coding is utf8_general_ci so it is not a problem.

I also have tried to encode it many times with utf8_decode/encode, json_endcode/decode and others without a success.

Please share with me your wisdom.

[image: Controller passing results screen]

[image: Debug outcome]

[image: Blade calling place]

[image: Output in source]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag?

```
<?= json_encode($page_data->json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ?>
```

If you don't want to escape slashes either, that would be the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag:

```
<?= json_encode($page_data->json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I tired and it's super improvement, but still I url(special characters - slashes are stying problem):
{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"JobPosting","title":"【唐津駅】≪完全週休2日制・社会保険完備・毎週2連休・高月給スタート≫技術だけで

like this schema above. thank you very much !

Comment: @くらしナビjakub That would be another flag JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES